# Levels of logging in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a package that puts Info and Warning levels of logging. I mean the following: For package pycounters only be sent to ERROR sentry. Everything else is going to file. Of all the other packages I want to send WARNING and ERROR to sentry. Here's some code. How to add it to happen?

```
'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['sentry', 'file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
```

**Solution:**

Real name of the logging that was registered by pycounters is: 'pycounters_multi_proc', when I asked it logging in the following way:

```
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'pycounters_multi_proc': {
            'handlers': ['sentry', 'file',],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['sentry', 'file'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True,
        },
```